# Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a definite divergent sequence. Prove that $\frac{1}{a_n}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a definite divergent sequence. Prove that $\frac{1}{a_n}$ converges to $0$.

I don't know if the translation is correct, definite divergence means a sequence diverges to $\infty$ or -$\infty$. So it's obvious that the whole term converges to $0$ but how do I prove it?

Comment: Let $r>0$ be given. Then $\exists N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_n|>1/r$ for all $n>N$ so ...

Comment: Have you tried to write down the definition for every concept in the statement?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $a_n \to \pm \infty$, then for all $K$ you can find $N$ such that $|a_n|>K$ when $n \ge N$.

For $\tfrac{1}{a_n}$ to tend to $0$, you need that for all $\varepsilon>0$, you can find $N$ such that $\left| \tfrac{1}{a_n} \right|< \varepsilon$ when $n \ge N$.

Can you puzzle these together?